# call php script from an html form

Tags: php, html, forms

This is my first time posting a question... I've tried my best to search the archives and try to solve this to no avail... so this is not out of laziness but more out of inexperience/ignorance. Anyways, onto my question:

I have the following html part of a form:

```
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="script.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Tell me your name</legend>

            First Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

            Submit:     <input type="submit" value="send">

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And the file script.php contains the following:

```
<?php
   $name = "empty";
   if(!empty($_POST["name"]))
   {
     $name = $_POST["name"];
   }
   echo $name;
 ?>
```

Very simple/beginner stuff. When I submit the form, I am sent to a new page which prints either "empty" or anything I'd typed into the name form-field.

My question: How can I execute this script from any html page containing a form without having the browser redirect me to a new page which contains the script output? I want to run a script in the background/not leave the current page (not necessarily for printing a message, but maybe to store whatever I type into the form fields into a database for example). I've tried typing this into the 'action' part of the form (in the html file):

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

And it redirects me to another page and shows the error:

> Not Found The requested URL /< was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please dont shout, it hurts my eyes

Comment: ajax, my friend. ajax

Comment: i agree with ajax, but you can post to page, and then redirect back (it will be almost instant), most people are not going to notice(or care)

Comment: For a beginner, you can do simple posts with redirects. Learn how PHP and HTML work and what each one can do individually, then you can start to learn how to make them talk.

Comment: Alright. I'm starting to learn javascript from a good manual... but I'm not proficient at it (I'm learning fundamentals at the moment and haven't worked with an API)... but how can I post to a page, and then redirect back (thanks for the suggestion nogad)?

Comment: i suck at JS so i use jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ajax it is then nogad... but, how can I (momentarily) solve this issue by doing the redirect (posting and redirecting back as you suggested)? It this something I can achieve with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Either combine the code into a single page:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $name = ....
   etc...
}
?>

<html>
<body>
... form ...
</body>
</html>
```

so that the code only triggers when the form is actually submitted (and not when the form is initially loaded).

Or you use AJAX to perform a background submission, leaving the original page intact and displayed to the user.

Comment: If I combine the code into a single page... what should I put as a value in the action part of the html form?